# How to use the Application "SharePoint ULS Log Viewer"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow

Goal:
I want to review the log number "Client ActivityId : 66605702-15be-46f7-901a-9125dec855b8"

Problem:
I have downloaded the application "SharePoint ULS Log Viewer" and tried locating the error number in the map "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS".

The main problem is that I do not know what notepad file I should go reviewing?

Information:
I'm using SP2013

[image]

Comment: you can open a few log files simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for but I'll give it a try.

If I understand correctly you are trying to find events in your SharePoint event log with that specific Client ActivityId and you want to view those events in the SharePoint ULS Log Viewer application.

Each log file in that folder only covers a period of time (on my server about 15 minutes).  Use the file date/time stamps and locate the range of time you want to search. Open each log file in the SharePoint ULS Log Viewer and search for that ActivityID in whatever field you think it would appear in.

Answer (score 0):

ULS Viewer is a great tool - but also consider the alternative powershell (especially if using multiple servers)

Merge-SPlogFile

You can use it to pull back all log entries for a specific correlation ID from all servers.

```
Merge-SPlogFile -correlation <corr. id here> -path <path of where to save output as txt file >
```

There are many more options available as well such as limiting the return of data to specific time ranges.